# Mounted volume EBS on AWS EC2 reports empty folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, mount, mounted-volumes

I have been trying to mount a volume on a EC2 instance on Amazon. I have used this command to attach the preexisting 550 GB volume to my instance:

```
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-XXXXX  --instance-id  i-XXXXX  --device /dev/sdf
```

After that, I connect to the instance and run the following commands;

```
ext_disk="/dev/sdf" 
sudo mkfs -t ext4  $ext_disk
sudo mkdir /mnt/test
sudo mount $ext_disk /mnt/test 
sudo chmod 777 -R /mnt/test/
```

No errors are reported when creating the file system or mounting the volume on the specifically created volume.

The problem is that when I try to access the data that is inside of this mounted folder, there are no files, it is empty. Also, `df -h` reports that the volume is mounted to that same /mnt/test folder and it has 550GB, but it is empty!

Comment: I have also tried to mount an S3 bucket with the same data that is inside the volume and the folder is also empty

Comment: Sadly, your question is not clear. You formatted the volume, so why would there any any pre-existing data there?

Comment: When you ran `mkfs` you deleted any data that was on the volume. You should not run `mkfs` every time you mount an EBS volume, only the first time you create it.